# Enable, add and edit navigation links in Wordpress main menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, menu, navigation

I installed WordPress yesterday. I want to try to change the navigation links however no menus are listed and when I create one it still does not change.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please note that: *"Questions about general computing software (settings) are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about)"*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the theme, but you can create and edit menus in `Appearance>>Menus`. then in the tab Manage Location you can declare which one is used in `Primary` , `Vertical` or `Mobile Navigation`. You can also declare that in `Appearance>Customize>>Menu`

If you change the menu but it doesn't appear will be necesary to see how it appears in your Menu listing.
Here is how mine looks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc9fJ.jpg (Appearance>Menu)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6apGK.jpg (Appearance>Customize>Menu)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlbBH.jpg (How it looks in my theme)

**How it looks in yours?**

In another note, sometimes some changes can't be processed/submited because that change requiered a lot of memory (Customize option). Do you have some other plugins installed? Have you tried to change to a Lite theme? (like Storefront?).

Hope this help you.

Comment: It just doesn't have any time of menu that I can edit.

Comment: Any Theme compatible with Woocommerce/Wordpress must have a way to edit menus. Have you tried with Storefront?